# How to change the color of btn-default in css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am unable to change the color the button.The class is "btn-default".
I can see only half button color when I hover the mouse onto it.
Here is my html code:

```
  <div class="pageOne">
        <div class="block text-center">
            <h1  id="header_text1"> a Good Tree production </h1>
            <h2  id="header_text2">We Review What We Watch</h2>
        </div>
    <div class="btnList">
         <a class="btn btn-default" href = "#"> a Good Tree production</a>
         <a class="btn btn-default" href = "#"> About Us</a>
         <a class="btn btn-default" href = "#"> Contact Us</a>
         <a class="btn btn-default" href = "#"> Works</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#header_text2{
 font-family: 'Jura', sans-serif;
 color: white;
 font-weight: 400;
}

.btn-default{
    background-color: black !important;
    color: #0D9E69;
    font-family: 'Barrio', cursive;
    border-radius: 0px;
    font-size: 20px !important;
}

.pageOne{
background-image:url("./container2.jpg");
background-size:cover;
height:450px;
}
```

Here is my live output link:

https://jsfiddle.net/VijayVj7/6k8y8ehL/1/

Please could anyone help me out on this

Comment: Bootstrap uses a background-image on `.btn-default`, so you need to override that as well.

Answer (score 0):

just add

```
.btn-default:hover {
    background: #333;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your can change your background position to:

```
.btn-default:focus, .btn-default:hover {
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    background-position: 0 -50px;
}
```

Or

```
.btn-default:focus, .btn-default:hover {
    background: #e0e0e0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line to your existing css `background-image: none !important;`

**Check this working snippet**--

```css
.btn-default{
        background-color: black !important;
        color: #0D9E69;
        font-family: 'Barrio', cursive;
        border-radius: 0px;
        font-size: 20px !important;
        background-image: none !important;
    }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          
          </head>
          <body>
 <div class="pageOne">
        <div class="block text-center">
            <h1  id="header_text1"> a Good Tree production </h1>
            <h2  id="header_text2">We Review What We Watch</h2>
        </div>
    <div class="btnList">
         <a class="btn btn-default" href = "#"> a Good Tree production</a>
         <a class="btn btn-default" href = "#"> About Us</a>
         <a class="btn btn-default" href = "#"> Contact Us</a>
         <a class="btn btn-default" href = "#"> Works</a>
    </div>
</div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

TRY THIS should work--

```
   .btn-default{
    background-color: black !important;
    color: #0D9E69;
    font-family: 'Barrio', cursive;
    border-radius: 0px;
    font-size: 20px !important;
    background-image: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need to do is:

```
background-image: none;
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution of your problem is to add `background-image:none !important;`
inside btn-default in your css so it will look like this

```
    .btn-default{
    background-color: black !important;
    color: #0D9E69;
    font-family: 'Barrio', cursive;
    border-radius: 0px;
    font-size: 20px !important;
    background-image: none !important;
}
```

Now the problem of modifying the btn-default is that it will remove the btn-default's design purpose. I suggest that you add your own class  with background color black and use it instead of the btn-default to avoid general changes to boostrap. for example in your code, change the btn-default to my-btn-default from your html code and also into your css code so the code will look like this

```
.my-btn-default{
    background-color: black !important;
    color: #0D9E69;
    font-family: 'Barrio', cursive;
    border-radius: 0px;
    font-size: 20px !important;
  background-image:none !important;
}
```

and in html

```
  <div class="btnList">
     <a class="btn my-btn-default" href = "#"> a Good Tree production</a>
     <a class="btn my-btn-default" href = "#"> About Us</a>
     <a class="btn my-btn-default" href = "#"> Contact Us</a>
     <a class="btn my-btn-default" href = "#"> Works</a>
  </div>
```

in this way it will not break any from bootstrap.